# docker-compose - how to escape environment variables

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose

With `docker-compose` v2 environment variables can be set by simply:

```
enviroment:
  - MONGO_PATH=mongodb://db-mongo:27017
```

The full `docker-compose.yml` file being:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      - MONGO_PATH=mongodb://db-mongo:27017
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    depends_on: 
      - db-mongo
      - db-redis
  db-mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: --smallfiles
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
  [...]
```

However, how can I escape environment variables that are not a plain string?

```
{"database": {"data": {"host": "mongo"}}}
```

I tried:

```
NODE_CONFIG=\{"database": \{"data"\: \{"host": "mongo"\}, "session": \{"host": "redis" \}\}\}
NODE_CONFIG="\{"database": \{"data"\: \{"host": "mongo"\}, "session": \{"host": "redis" \}\}\}"
NODE_CONFIG='{"database": {"data": {"host": "mongo"}, "session": {"host": "redis" }}}'
```

> ERROR: yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping   in
>   "./docker-compose.yml", line 6, column 9 expected , but
>   found '}'   in "./docker-compose.yml", line 6, column 92

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Environment variables (including their name), **have to be fully wrapped inside single or double quotes**: `""` or `''`

```
environment:
  - 'NODE_CONFIG={"database": {"data": {"host": "mongo"}, "session": {"host": "redis" }}}'
```

And using double quotes:

```
environment:
  - 'PORT=3000'
  - "NODE_CONFIG={\"database\": {\"data\": {\"host\": \"mongo\"}, \"session\": {\"host\": \"redis\" }}}"
```

It is remarkable to note that using double quotes `""`, like bash, will allow placing variables inside the environment variable.

```
"MY_HOME_ENV_VARIABLE=${HOME}"
```

Comment: docker compose should not allow you to do that without quotes!!

Comment: See also: [Inconsistent env var parsing from docker-compose.yml #2854](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2854)

Comment: @TomislavMikulin did you figured out how to do with an env file?

Comment: Support for quotes to be expected in 1.26: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2854#issuecomment-628020801

Comment: Doesn't work. Single-quotes do not escape a dollar-sign. e.g. `- 'MYVAR=$GJ'` will try to parse `$GJ` as a variable from the docker env file. See `https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5965`. A double-dollar `$$` needs to be used to represent one escaped `$`.

Comment: Why is it that in a Dockerfile it's different, it does not like your double quotes example, you have to put double quotes on the value of the variable.