# CORS blocking API call from Dockerized React project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm having issues running a detached dockerized React app that makes Restful calls to a dockerized Node.js microservice. The issues that I'm having is that the requests are blocked by the CORS policy with the following error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/api/restaurants/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value '"http://172.28.1.1:3000"'.`

There is a url environment variable the I use to set the accepted cors header when the container is run up. I have used the same technique to make requests between 2 headless apps. Is there something about React that means this will not work?

I have tried setting the IP addresses in the docker-compose in order to pass in as the CORSHEADER env variable. I've added the relevant code below.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web-ui-service:
    container_name: web-ui-service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - restaurant-data-service
    networks:
      vegitable_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.29.1.1

  restaurant-data-service:
    image: timhaydenhawkins/restaurant-data-service
    environment:
      CORSHEADER: "http://172.29.1.1:3000"
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    networks:
      vegitable_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.29.1.2

networks:
  vegitable_net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.29.0.0/16
```

Cors header setting in restaurant-data-service

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', process.env.CORSHEADER);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, 
DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested- 
With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
}
```

This techniques has worked fine in headless apps in containers but having real issues with it working for React. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the environment variables in the api set correctly for the CORS header?

Comment: as a test just check `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` works?

Comment: Yes, works fine with '*', and the environment variable is getting passed correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your node application should support CORS, if you are using express, you should 
add the following lines in the app.js file

`const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());`

Answer (score 1):

> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value **'"http://172.28.1.1:3000"'**

1. It looks like the quotes are being treated as being part of the environment variable value:

`environment:
 - CORSHEADER="http://172.28.1.1:3000"
 - PROXY=true`

Should be:

`environment:
  CORSHEADER: "http://172.28.1.1:3000"
  PROXY: true`

(though, you can escape it too: [docker-compose - how to escape environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988809/docker-compose-how-to-escape-environment-variables))

2. The `docker-compose.yml` you shared appears to be malformed:

`environment:
       - NODE_ENV=development
     depends_on:
      - restaurant-data-service`

The indentation at this bit is inconsistent with the rest of the `web-ui-service` keys. It does not parse correctly, but this may have been an accident?

Comment: I've changed the environment variable to the format you've and it's in single quotes now. Still getting the Cors error though. I think the indentation issue was from pasting the code in SO, it's correct in my file

Comment: Mind sharing the current state of things? (code / config that is, and the CORS error)

Comment: i've edited the original question to the current state

Comment: It doesn't look too happy with the value it is getting from the environment. It is not being parsed correctly for whatever reason. I would try hardcoding the value. I assume you are not using Webpack by any chance for `restaurant-data-service` ? Apart from that, I believe you should also be setting your origin as `http://localhost:3000`.