# Docker YAML enviroment for spring.datasource.password have symbols. How do i work this around?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, yaml

Okay so I have a yaml file for deploying a spring boot image. So i want to set my spring datasource password in my environment yaml. But when I use `docker-compose up` , it shows error

```
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "apps": "spring.datasource.password= "my_password!@#$"
```

I believe that this error occured because my datasource password has symbols in it. How do I resolve it?

Here is my .yml file:

```
version: '3.0'

    services:    
        apps:
                image: student
                ports:
                - 8085:8080
                environment:
                - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.100.3/my_database
                - spring.datasource.username= my_user
                - spring.datasource.password= my_password!@#$
```

Comment: did you try to put it in double quote? `"spring.datasource.password= my_password!@#$"`, and this might help too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988809/docker-compose-how-to-escape-environment-variables/41988810

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` at the end signals to Compose that it needs to do [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution); without an actual environment variable name after it, you get the "invalid interpolation" error.  To get around this:

> You can use a `$$` (double-dollar sign) when your configuration needs a literal dollar sign.

So set:

```
- spring.datasource.password=my_password!@#$$
```

(Double-check: should the username and password begin with spaces?  You might need to remove the space after the equals sign, the [`environment:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment) documentation does not show spaces here and does not suggest it removes whitespace from values.)