# Different results with docker run and docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using this image to mount an unionfs filesystem. When I run the container with `docker run`, it works perfectly, but when I put the same conditions into `docker-compose`, it doesn't work. It seem to be an issue with the environmental variable (I suspect).

docker-compose config:

```
  unionfs:
    container_name: unionfs
    image: meyay/unionfs-mount:alpha
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
      - PUID=1000
      - GUID=1000
      - READ_ONLY_DIR="/read-only/m/ro"
      - READ_WRITE_DIR="/read-write/m/rw"
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/sshfs:/read-write:slave
      - /mnt/gdrive:/read-only:slave
      - /mnt/unionfs/tvs:/merged:shared
```

`docker-compose up` gives me this error in the container: `Failed to open /run/s6/services/unionfs/"/read-write/m/rw"/: No such file or directory. Aborting!`

If I run the same image with `docker run`:

```
docker run --rm \
--name unionfs \
-e TZ="Europe/Berlin" \
-e PUID=1000 \
-e GUID=1000 \
-e READ_ONLY_DIR="/read-only/m/ro" \
-e READ_WRITE_DIR="/read-write/m/rw" \
--privileged \
-v /home/ubuntu/sshfs:/read-write:slave \
-v /mnt/gdrive:/read-only:slave \
-v /mnt/unionfs/tvs:/merged:shared \
meyay/unionfs-mount:alpha
```

then the unionfs mount will be mounted successfully. Is there any reason why is this happening? They are both identical, right?

Comment: The image is a custom one I built from this github repo: https://github.com/meyayl/docker-unionfs-mount

Comment: It seems that it includes the quotes. Write it like this: `READ_WRITE_DIR=/read-write/m/rw` (the other one analogous) and see if it helps.

Comment: @toydarian YES that did the job. Why though? Isn't it better to write the environmental variables within quotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here are the quotes, which are treated differently, as you specify the variables in a yaml-file.

You need to write it like this:

```
  unionfs:
    container_name: unionfs
    image: meyay/unionfs-mount:alpha
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
      - PUID=1000
      - GUID=1000
      - "READ_ONLY_DIR=/read-only/m/ro"
      - "READ_WRITE_DIR=/read-write/m/rw"
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/sshfs:/read-write:slave
      - /mnt/gdrive:/read-only:slave
      - /mnt/unionfs/tvs:/merged:shared
```

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41988809/docker-compose-how-to-escape-environment-variables) as well.
And I just found [this issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2854#issuecomment-628020801) on GitHub.